# In React, I'm not receiving anything back from my fetch request to the backend

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, asynchronous, fetch

I'm trying to signup a user using React. I am using a rails backend. In rails my create action looks like this.

```
def create
    user = User.new(user_params)
    if user.save
        render json: user
    else
        render json: {error: 'Cannot create user'}
    end
end
```

Then in my React app I'm dispatching the action like this...

```
export const submitForm = (formData) => {
return dispatch => {
    return fetch('/api/users', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ user: formData })
    }).then(response => {debugger})
}
```

}

I've verified that the user is being saved to the database correctly on the backend. However, I never hit my debugger. It's like I"m not getting anything back and my .then never hits?

Any idea what's going on?

Comment: What's in the logs when doing the request?

Comment: I figured out the issue. I forgot to preventDefault() on the event handler which was causing the promise not to fire.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to preventDefault() on the event handler. This was causing it from firing correctly.